# Unable To Trust Self-Signed SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl, openssl

I have an application running on Centos7 that needs to connect to a remote host over HTTPS. However, it is unable to verify the certificate and fails. Also, if I try to download a file from the server using wget, I get the below error:

```
[root@foo:~]# wget https://10.65.127.9/index.html

--2017-05-22 09:03:01--  https://10.65.127.9/index.html
Connecting to 10.65.127.9:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify 10.65.127.9's certificate, issued by ‘/CN=us6877vnxe7827’:
Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to 10.65.127.9 insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

So I get the certificate from the host:

```
openssl s_client -connect 10.65.127.9:443 <<<'' | openssl x509 -out /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/mycert.pem
```

And execute the following to process it:

```
update-ca-trust extract
```

This however results in the same issue.. If I run:

```
openssl s_client -connect 10.65.127.9:443 -showcerts -debug
```

I do get some errors and various messages:

```
depth=0 CN = us6877vnxe7827
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = us6877vnxe7827
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
0 s:/CN=us6877vnxe7827
i:/CN=us6877vnxe7827
Server certificate
subject=/CN=us6877vnxe7827
issuer=/CN=us6877vnxe7827
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
```

Any ideas what I may be missing? If any further info helps, please let me know.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

For `wget` you need to provide the certificate authority (CA) certificate(s) that signed the https server certificate. If you have those CA certificates - add them under `--ca-certificate=file` or `--ca-directory=directory` options

If you don't have them and you want to skip https server certificate verification (unsecure and can be dangerous) then use `--no-check-certificate` option.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was able to get my hands on one of the CA certs of a server that has a properly signed certificate and point wget at it (--ca-certificate=file). However, what about a self-signed certificate? From my research, I believe I should be able to use `openssl s_client -connect 10.65.127.9:443` to get the cert, but what it pulls does not seem to work.

Comment: To be more specific, the wget returns "Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority" after directing it to the cert. I also exported the certificate out of Firefox after adding it as an exception. It is the exactly same cert I get from using openssl and results in the same outcome.

Comment: A self-signed certificate is its own CA certificate

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Jenkins trying to connect to our GitLab server.
The server does have a valid official certificate in our case, but Java didn't except it.

You are right about downloading the certificate.

However, the application you are mentioning is probably running inside a Java Virtual Machine (as a lot of applications are).
So from the point that you downloaded the certificate to a PEM file, you may have to add it to the VM's trusted certificates instead.

[This article](http://lib.openlog.it/2014/09/14/jenkins-git-repository-and-self-signed-certificate/) describes how to do that. Hope it helps.